# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 how fix?

Tags: java, android

sorry i just learning to use AsyncTask, but I am having a problem when running my code..

I have three class
The first class for RestClient

```
public class LoginPembayaran {

private static final String urlServer = "https://webservicetagihan.herokuapp.com";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

public void login(String username, String password) throws GagalLoginException{
    Map<String, String> logindata = new HashMap<>();
    logindata.put("username",username);
    logindata.put("password",password);

    Map<String,Object> hasil = restTemplate.postForObject(urlServer + "/api/login",logindata,Map.class,new Object[]{});

    if (hasil == null ){
        throw new GagalLoginException("Respon valid");
    }

    if (!(Boolean)hasil.get("sukses")){
        throw new GagalLoginException("user name / password salah");
    }


}
```

class two for AsyncTask..

```
public class loginAktifity extends Fragment {
private LoginPembayaran loginPembayaran = new LoginPembayaran();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_login,container,false);

    Button button = (Button)fragment.findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String username = ((EditText)fragment.findViewById(R.id.Etusernama)).getText().toString();
                    String password = ((EditText)fragment.findViewById(R.id.EtPassword)).getText().toString();

                    new AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>(){

                        String ErrorMassage;
                        @Override
                        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                            try {
                                loginPembayaran.login(params[0], params[1]);
                                return true;
                            }catch (GagalLoginException err){
                                ErrorMassage = err.getMessage();
                                return false;
                            }
                        };


                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean sukses) {
                            if(sukses){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SesudahLoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),ErrorMassage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute(username,password);


                }
            }
    );
    return fragment;
}
```

}

Class tree for Exception

```
public class GagalLoginException extends Exception {
public GagalLoginException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

my logcat..

```
    03-18 09:57:35.780 30964-31227/com.khoiron.apptagihan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  Process: com.khoiron.apptagihan, PID: 30964
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.khoiron.apptagihan.RestClient.LoginPembayaran.login(LoginPembayaran.java:31)
      at com.khoiron.apptagihan.Fragment.loginAktifity$1$1.doInBackground(loginAktifity.java:48)
      at com.khoiron.apptagihan.Fragment.loginAktifity$1$1.doInBackground(loginAktifity.java:41)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
      12q
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please help me n Please guide me....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for more suggestions about how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's line 31

```
if (!(boolean)hasil.get("sukses")){
```

So you made a typo with label, get() returns null and casting it to boolean causes NPE.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception log, you can see that the exception is originated from `LoginPembayaran.login`, line 31.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.khoiron.apptagihan.RestClient.LoginPembayaran.login(LoginPembayaran.java:31)
```

As already mentioned in the other answer, it's possible that the map `hasil` do not contain the key item `sukses`, hence the exception.

To debug this problem, you can use Android Studio's debugger (see [official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)) and set a breakpoint in line 31, to inspect if the map `hasil` indeed contains the key `sukses`.